# Best scaleable way to find many keywords in a large amount of text?

Tags: php

Ever few minutes around 500 paragraphs are supposed to be submitted to the database in a table called "Content" (this number will go to over 2,500 in a few months).
There is another table called "Keywords" which has over 4,000 rows (and is expected to grow to over 10,000).

```
Keywords
+------------+-------------------+
| Keyword_id | keyword           |
+------------+-------------------+
|          1 | "Venture Capital" |
|          2 | "Financing"       |
+------------+-------------------+
```

The question is: **What is the best way to scale a solution where each keyword is cross-referenced among an incoming paragraphs of text to see if there is a match?**

Since I'm not concerned about where in the paragraph there is a match (my only concern is that there IS a match);
`if(preg_match()){}` could possibly work but even at the low-end that's 2,000,000 times you're running over a paragraph searching for a keyword.
Plus, correct me if I'm wrong, preg_match is pretty expensive.

One of the possibilites that crossed my mind was to keep an array of the keywords in the cache instead of having to call on the DB for every row.
That would definitely help speed things up I think.

I'm not concerned with this being only in PHP.
If this section of the application needs to be in Python (correct me if I'm wrong, but I hear Python is a lot less expensive at parsing text), then I'm all ears.

Comment: why don't you use the DB directly for that?
a lot of RDBMS have strong full-text features and are really fast in doing this...

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Since I'm not a DB-guru, would that be doing something such as the 'like' statement in mysql?  My apologies if I'm far off; I've always dealt more with the php side of things and not so much the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MySQL:

Search query: `Vent Capit`

Using [match against](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

```
SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE MATCH (keyword) AGAINST ('+Vent* +Capit*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

If your using `_ci` collation, (ci stands for case insensitive), the matching would ignore capitalization :)

Comment: Would this be dramatically faster than say running a script from an array with preg_match()?  The reason why I ask is because (and please correct me if I'm wrong) is it not insanely easier to scale computing (such as with amazon) but insanely hard to scale a database to 40,000,000 queries / few minutes?  Basically: is the speed worth the cost of not being able to scale as easily?

Comment: A couple of days later and some speed tests and I can confirm that this is the correct answer by large and far compared to doing it via parsing text through preg_match().  While I'm not sure if this way will be scalable in the long-run, it should suffice definitely for now.  I'll update this as time goes on to let you (and everyone else) know how it goes.  Thanks.